# SQL putting two single quotes around datetime fields and fails to insert record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, double-quotes

I am trying to INSERT into an SQL database table, but it doesn't work. So I used the SQL server profiler to see how it was building the query; what it shows is the following:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=0
declare @p2 int
set @p2=0
declare @p3 int
set @p3=1
exec InsertProcedureName @ConsumerMovingDetailID=@p1 output, @UniqueID=@p2 output, 
                         @ServiceID=@p3 output, @ProjectID=N'0', @IPAddress=N'66.229.112.168', 
                         @FirstName=N'Mike', @LastName=N'P', @Email=N'mymail@yahoo.com', 
                         @PhoneNumber=N'(254)637-1256', @MobilePhone=NULL, @CurrentAddress=N'', 
                         @FromZip=N'10005', @MoveInAddress=N'', @ToZip=N'33067', 
                         @MovingSize=N'1', @MovingDate=''2009-04-30 00:00:00:000'', 
                               /*        Problem here  ^^^  */
                         @IsMovingVehicle=0, @IsPackingRequired=0, @IncludeInSaveologyPlanner=1
select @p1, @p2, @p3
```

As you can see, it puts <del>a double quote</del> two pairs of single quotes around the datetime fields, so that it produces a syntax error in SQL.
I wonder if there is anything I must configure somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the environment details:

- Visual Studio 2008
- .NET 3.5
- MS SQL Server 2005

Here is the .NET code I'm using....

```
//call procedure for results
strStoredProcedureName = "usp_SMMoverSearchResult_SELECT";

Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand(strStoredProcedureName);
dbCommand.CommandTimeout = DataHelper.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;

database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@MovingDetailID", DbType.String, objPropConsumer.ConsumerMovingDetailID);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FromZip", DbType.String, objPropConsumer.FromZipCode);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ToZip", DbType.String, objPropConsumer.ToZipCode);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@MovingDate", DbType.DateTime, objPropConsumer.MoveDate);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@PLServiceID", DbType.Int32, objPropConsumer.ServiceID);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FromAreaCode", DbType.String, pFromAreaCode);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@FromState", DbType.String, pFromState);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ToAreaCode", DbType.String, pToAreaCode);
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@ToState", DbType.String, pToState);

DataSet dstSearchResult = new DataSet("MoverSearchResult");
database.LoadDataSet(dbCommand, dstSearchResult, new string[] { "MoverSearchResult" });
```

Comment: Could you also post the codes that generate this SQL query? The problem is very apparent (double quotes and colon between secs and millisecs), so the root of your problem must be in the piece of code that generated this query.

Comment: post your .net code since the date information is coming from there correct?

Comment: Can you post the code (or a sample that reproduces the problem) that's building the query in the first place, best to work from the front in than the back out.

Comment: Your database factory is not part of the core .Net library, and it looks like that's where your bug is (specifically: in the AddInParameter function).  We'll need to see that, too.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Enterprise Library. AddInParameter function is part of Enterprise Library January 2006.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are adding single quotes to your datetime field, and sending it as a string?  Don't do that.  Use a datetime type for the parameter and don't add any quotes to it.

It would help if you showed us the .Net side of the code.

Comment: @Neil Wow, this is old, but I'll bite.  The code he posted doesn't prove this there are no quotes there.  He doesn't share the code for the `objPropConsumer` type, and so it's possible or even likely that it's MoveDate member is just a string.

Comment: Go and take a look at the SQL output by profiler in his question and see "Problem here  ^^^" just below the incorrectly quoted time field. It's a bug in that version of profiler. I'm only trying to tidy things up for future searchers - me included in that.

Answer (score 1):

SP2 or SP3 should solve this issue in Profiler

Comment: This fixes it. See also: http://geekswithblogs.net/influent1/archive/2007/05/31/112897.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'2009-04-30 00:00:00.000'
```

Note the single-quotes and "." instead of ":" for the milliseconds.  Or try this:

```
'2009-04-30 00:00:00'
```

To make sure it's not the milliseconds.

Comment: I've added my .NET code in original post. BTW.. I'm using datetime parameters and not adding any quote too.

Answer (score 0):

Is objPropConsumer.MoveDate a string? It looks like it is populated with a string that has apostrophes at the beginning and end. Try replacing the objPropConsumer.MoveDate with a constant '2009-04-30 00:00:00' and see if that works. If it does, the problem lies where the MoveDate is set or converted.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for the problem in your Database class. Perhaps the `AddInParameter()` method performs some jiggery-pokery with DateTime parameters, like adding a formatted string or something silly like that.

For use with MSSQL, the `CreateStoredProc()` absolutely should return an instance of `SqlCommand` (there are other subclasses of DbCommand which you don't want to use). Verify that, then ensure that the `AddInParameter()` adds an instance of `SqlParameter` to the Parameters collection, that its `DbType` property is `DbType.DateTime` and its `Value` property is of type `System.DateTime`.

Once parameters are properly added to a `SqlCommand`, it should work well with MSSQL stored procedures, also with DateTime data (it has for me, zillions of times).

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same thing - it turns out that the two single quotes were only showing up in the profiler. The underlying (actual) error was that I was passing too many arguments to the stored procedure.